# Apache spark querying columnar data

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have been looking at Apache Spark 2.0 and trying to use Spark SQL to process some data in text files. The data is structured as follows

1
Bob
London
2014

2
Robert
Paris
2016

3
Sam
Rome
2011

How would I run SparkSQL queries on data schema such as this.

I also realize spark provides various options to read data sources.

**spark.read.**

*csv,jdbc,load,options,parquet,table,textFile

format,json,option,orc,schema,text*

Could anyone of these be used?

Comment: I recommend you convert before the file to CSV format

Comment: The files are too large 45 to 60 gigs

Comment: See here: https://www.mapr.com/blog/spark-data-source-api-extending-our-spark-sql-query-engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the task for me

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter","\n\n")
spark.sparkContext.textFile("File.txt")
```